# How ant matcher works in spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to know how ant matcher works in spring security??

I have two rest point:
First Rest class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
class RestService1{

      @GetMapping("/status")
      public String status() {
          return "Yes, I am fine";
     }
 }
```

Second Rest class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
class RestService2{

      @GetMapping("/status")
      public String status() {
          return "Yes, Test status";
     }
 }
```

Spring security config class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{       
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception{
      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/*").permitAll();
  }
 }
```

Here is my question:

As per my understanding the meaning of "antMatchers("/auth/*").permitAll()" line is permit all request urls who contains "auth". But with this code I can able to access localhost:8080/test/status URL as well.

So what i can do if i want to allow only "auth" contains URL and deny all URLs ?

Answer (score 1):

This code will permit only request URLs starting with "auth" and will deny all other URLs.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .denyAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

anyRequest().authenticate() will make all other routes forbidden, one has to be authenticated before accessing those routes.

```
@Configuration
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticate();
    }
}
```